# How to configure laravel-vue-pagination for Nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

1. installed via

```
npm i laravel-vue-pagination
```

2. created a file under plugins folder as "laravel-vue-pagination.js"

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import LaravelVuePagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination'

Vue.use('laravel-vue-pagination', LaravelVuePagination)
```

3. registered in nuxt.config.js under plugins array

```
'~/plugins/laravel-vue-pagination'
```

4. using in page as follows

```
<LaravelVuePagination :data="users" @pagination-change-page="getResults"></LaravelVuePagination>
```

5. Getting error

**Cannot create property '**nuxt_external_installed**' on string 'laravel-vue-pagination'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are registering it as a plugin, but this is a component, and require registration as a component:

```
Vue.component('laravel-vue-pagination', LaravelVuePagination)
```

Note: The syntax for registering a plugin is also wrong. The first parameter of Vue.use() is the plugin to register.